# How to count HTML child tag in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium JAVA WebDriver - How can I count child tags?
Example:

```
<div class="subcategory_container">
  <div class="products_container">
     <div class="product_row">
       <form class="product_container">
       <form class="product_container">
       <form class="product_container">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to count how many **form** tag are there under **product_row div**?
Thanks

Comment: I would probably use an xpath expression: //xpath-to-element[count(childExpression)]

Comment: Actually: `count(//div[@class='product_row']/form[@class='product_container'])` to be rather specific

Comment: @DanielChapman: This won't result in any elements. Selenium can only deal with actual elements, not XPath's text or count etc.

Comment: Really? That's good information. I'll verify it tonight.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me out. @User1177636 your script worked in one shot didn't try others but will give a shot to others  now - Again appreciated all yours help.

Answer (score 13):

You find the parent div first, then locate all target elements, then count them.

```
List<WebElement> forms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".product_row form"));
int count = forms.size();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are two solutions:

You could either select by xpath

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product_row']/form"))
```

or you could select by CSS query as mentioned by **user1177636**

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".product_row>form"))
```

Comment: @user1177636 They are two solutions to one question.

Comment: Instead of nitpicking the difference between the definitions of _answer_ and _solution_, we should focus on the question at hand.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the size of elements by using the following statement:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product_row']/form")).size());
```

Where `.findElements` method returns count value that all elements in that a page consists with xpath `//div[@class='product_row']/form`

In your case it will return "3" as result

Answer (score 1):

Every element has an attribute called childElementCount.
You can use WebElement.getAttribute() function to get an immediate value.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("product_row"));
int numberOfChilds = Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute("childElementCount"));
```

Because getAttribute() returns a String, we have to cast it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would use some way to find all of the elements that I want, either using xpath or css selectors, and then just count how many results are returned.