# How to find the index of HTML child tag in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: html, css, selenium

I am trying to find a way to return the index of a HTML child tag based on its xpath.

For instance, on the right rail of a page, I have three elements:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl50_g_3B684B74_3A19_4750_AA2A_FB3D56462880"]/div[1]/h4

//*[@id="ctl00_ctl50_g_3B684B74_3A19_4750_AA2A_FB3D56462880"]/div[2]/h4

//*[@id="ctl00_ctl50_g_3B684B74_3A19_4750_AA2A_FB3D56462880"]/div[3]/h4
```

Assume that I've found the first element, and I want to return the number inside the tag div, which is 1. How can I do it?

I referred to this previous post ([How to count HTML child tag in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553372/how-to-count-html-child-tag-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)) but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: what exactly is your task? Do you select one of the h4's by another query and now want to know its index? Or do you retrieve a list of elements by another selector and this are the individual xpath's?

Comment: I am trying to write a method which will return the index of a report in the right rail given the report's xpath. For instance, assume the report name is "hello1". My method will take in the name of the report, which is "hello 1", and returns this report's index on the right rail. "hello 1" could be the first one on the right rail, or the second, or the third. In order to get its index, I need to retrieve its xpath because the div tag inside the xpath has the index. Does my logic make sense?

Comment: Someone (perhaps you) who wrote those xpath expressions came up with the index right?

Comment: Hello! Sorry I am not quite sure what you are asking. I am just trying to figure out a way to retrieve the index number within the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can select preceeding sibling in xpath to get all the reports before your current one like this:

```
//h4[contains(text(),'hello1')]/preceding-sibling::h4
```

Now you only have to count how many you found plus the current and you have your index.

Another option would be to select all the reports at once and loop over them checking for their content. They always come in the same order they are in the dom.

for java it could look like this:

```
List<WebElement> reports = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ctl50_g_3B684B74_3A19_4750_AA2A_FB3D56462880']/div/h4")
for(WebElement element : reports){
    if(element.getText().contains("report1"){
         return reports.indexOf(element) + 1;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will have to parse the xpath by yourself to extract the value (see LG3527118's answer for this).

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much! I was thinking about for loop too.

Comment: Actually I tried the first line of your code, List <WebElement> .... And it did not work until I changed "List" to "IReadOnlyList". Do you happen to know why it is like that?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by it does not work? The [official api doc](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) defines the return value as a `List<WebElement>`.

Comment: I saw a red squiggly line below it, and the warning is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection <OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List <OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>'

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.52.0

Comment: What webDriver Implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number using regex:

```
var regExp = /div\[([^)]+)\]/;
var matches = regExp.exec("//[@id=\"ctl00_ctl50_g_3B684B74_3A19_4750_AA2A_FB3D56462880\"]/div[2]/h4");

console.log(matches[1]); \\ returns 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!